# Flash Standard Libraries?

Tags: flash, code-reuse, standard-library

For a new project with Flash I was looking for something along the lines of standard libraries for basic programming needs, along the lines of Python or Ruby standard libraries. But the only thing I found was a dead project on Sourceforge.

Thus is there no standard library for flash? Does everyone reinvent the wheel each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic libraries are [built into flash](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/). Then on top of that there is [flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/), which gives you an entire RIA framework. Then there are 3rd party frameworks for [3d](http://blog.papervision3d.org/), [physics engines](http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/), various design patterns ([MVC](http://puremvc.org/component/option,com_wrapper/Itemid,160/), [IoC](http://www.herrodius.com/blog/64) etc) to name just a few.

So no, you do not not to reinvent the wheel every time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, [the Flash Player API](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/) is the "standard library" for Flash applications (the `flash.*` packages).

For more application programming -oriented libraries, there are the [Flex standard libraries](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/) (the `mx.*` packages).